# Can we abstractly construct this ring and what is it isomorphic to?

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, twin-primes

Define $R = \Bbb{Z}[X_1, X_2, \dots]$.  Then place on $R$ the relations 
$$
X_1 + 1 = X_2, \\  X_2 + 2 = X_3, \\ X_3 + 2 = X_4, \\  X_5 + 2 = X_6, \dots \\ X_{2k-1} + 2 = X_{2k}, \ \forall k \geq 3
$$.

In other words, force the existence of the primes as we know them ($2 + 1 = 3, 3 + 2 = 5, 5+2 = 7, 11 + 2 = 13, \dots)$, making particularly sure there are infinitely many **twin prime** pairs $X_k, X_{k+1}$.  We can accomplish this by taking the quotient of $R$ with the ideal generated by: 
$$\{ X_1 - X_2 + 1, \\ X_2 - X_3 + 2, \\ X_3 - X_4 + 2, \\ X_{2k-1} - X_{2k} + 2, \\ \forall k \geq 3\}$$

Now if you prove that the ring $R/I$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}$ then I think that proves the twin prime conjecture.  If you prove that it's isomorphic to a ring containing $\Bbb{Z}$ then that may be of some interest as well.

So can you compute the quotient $R/I$ in some way?

Comment: I take it you mean $2,3,5,\ldots$?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff now can you see that it's related to TPC?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your quotient is $\,\cong\Bbb Z[X_1,\,X_5,X_7,X_9,X_{11},X_{13},\cdots]$. This is because in your quotient ring, $X_{2k}$ can be written in terms of $X_{2k-1}$ for $k\ge3$, and $X_4$ can be written in terms of $X_3$ which can be written in terms of $X_2$ which can be written in terms of $X_1$, and no other relations are imposed.

Notice also that primes are not even present in the definition of your quotient ring, so I see no connection between it and primes (let alone the twin prime conjecture).